# Airport transit visa for Lisbon

Tags: transit, airports, portugal, transit-visas, iranian-citizens

I am an Iranian passport holder flying from Tehran to Caracas via Turkey and Lisbon (TAP Portugal). The layover is around five hours at Lisbon and I have no Schengen visa of any type.

Do I need an airport transit / transit visa for Lisbon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pnuts commented, Iranian nationals need a transit visa to transit through any airport in the Schengen area, even when not leaving the airport transit area. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Airport_transit), or [portugal.com](http://www.portugal.com/information/visa).

This rule is enforced by the airlines, who will not let you board the flight *towards* Schengen without seeing an airport transit visa.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, I do need an airport visa if it's few hours and if I intend to have  a short stay in the city I need a transit visa (more than 12 hours)... thank you so much.

Comment: @Hannah: There used to be a form of Schengen transit visa (class B) which would you to leave the airport, but this was abolished in 2010 (though not all websites have caught on to that yet). Nowadays if you want to leave the airport during the layover you need to apply for an ordinary short-stay Schengen visa (class C).